# C List Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, list, segmentation-fault

I tried to implement linked lists in C. However, when i want to print the list it segfaults. This is probably because the list remains empty as I found out in debug mode. Where did I mess up (ofc neither AppendLast() nor AppendFirst() would work.) ? I didn't have any compiler errors or warnings. Here's my code:

main.c:

```
#include "listops.h"

int main(){
    list L, M;
    L = initList(L);
    M = initList(M);

    nodeData myNumbers[5] = {{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}};

    int i;
    ndp myNumbersPtr;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        myNumbersPtr = &myNumbers[i];
        AppendLast(L, myNumbersPtr);
    }

    printList(L);


    return 0;
}
```

listops.h:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef LISTOPS_H
#define LISTOPS_H

typedef struct NodeData{
    int myInt;
}nodeData, *ndp;

typedef struct Node{
    ndp data;
    struct Node* next;
} node, *nodeptr;

typedef struct List{
    nodeptr first;
    nodeptr last;
} list, *listptr;

list initList(list L){
    L.first = NULL;
    L.last = NULL;
    return L;
}

int isListEmpty(list L){
    return (L.first == NULL && L.last == NULL);
}

nodeptr createNode(ndp item){
    nodeptr np;
    np = (nodeptr)malloc(sizeof(node));
    np->data = item;
    np->next = NULL;
    return np;
}  

void AppendFirst(list L, ndp item){
    /* node erstellen */
    nodeptr np = createNode(item);
    /* Checken, ob Liste leer */
    if(isListEmpty(L)){
        L.first = np;
        L.last = np;
    }
    else{
        np->next = L.first;
        L.first = np;
    }
}

void AppendLast(list L, ndp item){
    nodeptr np = createNode(item);
    if(isListEmpty(L)){
        L.first = np;
        L.last = np;
    }
    else{
       L.last->next = np;
       np->next = NULL;
    }
}

void printList(list L){
    nodeptr np = L.first;
    int nodeCount = 1;
    while(np->next!=NULL){
        printf("data #%d: %d\n", nodeCount, np->data->myInt);
        nodeCount++;
        np = np->next;
    }
}

#endif // LISTOPS_H
```

Comment: In `AppendLast()` you forgot to set `L.last` but it is not the source of segmentation fault

Comment: Notice that nowhere in the AppendFirst() fuction do you update the "next" pointer of any node.

Comment: Don't pass structures by values. You are making copies on the stack instead of modifying original variables.

Comment: As far can understand when you print your list it should contain just the first and last elements (print dump just the first). But I cannot see where you can have a segmentation fault.

Comment: Thank you very much Valeri, that solved it for me. Well, it is still a long road to become good @ C.

Comment: Also, don't disguise pointer types with typedefs.  Among other things, it makes it harder to recognize when you are passing a structure by value, as you cannot rely on recognizing pointer types by the `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work, I made two changes to listops.h, apart from calling structs by reference now.

First, i replaced np->next = NULL in the else-branch of AppendLast() with
L->last = np.

Second, i changed the condition of the while-loop from np->next!=NULL
to np!=NULL.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef LISTOPS_H
#define LISTOPS_H

typedef struct NodeData{
    int myInt;
}nodeData, *ndp;

typedef struct Node{
    ndp data;
    struct Node* next;
} node, *nodeptr;

typedef struct List{
    nodeptr first;
    nodeptr last;
} list, *listptr;

list initList(list L){
    L.first = NULL;
    L.last = NULL;
    return L;
}

int isListEmpty(listptr L){
    return (L->first == NULL && L->last == NULL);
}

void AppendFirst(listptr L, ndp item){
    /* node erstellen */
    nodeptr np = createNode(item);
    /* Checken, ob Liste leer */
    if(isListEmpty(L)){
        L->first = np;
        L->last = np;
    }
    else{
        np->next = L->first;
        L->first = np;
    }
}

void AppendLast(listptr L, ndp item){
    nodeptr np = createNode(item);
    if(isListEmpty(L)){
        L->first = np;
        L->last = np;
    }
    else{
       L->last->next = np;
       L->last = np;
    }
}

   void printList(list L){
    nodeptr np = L.first;
    int nodeCount = 1;
    while(np!=NULL){
        printf("data #%d: %d\n", nodeCount, np->data->myInt);
        nodeCount++;
        np = np->next;
    }
}

#endif // LISTOPS_H
```